# onClick and onClientClick event used together. Does not Work in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

**Java script code:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validateLoginForm() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtTitle.ClientID%>").value == "") {

            alert("Please Enter Title");
            txtTitle.focus();
            return false;
        }
}
```

**Button Code**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPost"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"  Text="Post" OnClientClick="javascript:validateLoginForm();" runat="server" OnClick="btnPost_Click"  />
```

This code is not working on internet explorer but works fine in firefox
even though the javascript returns false in onClientClick event
the onClick event is still getting called 
Please Help...!!!

Comment: try this : OnClientClick="return validateLoginForm();"

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved using

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPost"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"  Text="Post" OnClientClick="return validateLoginForm();" runat="server" OnClick="btnPost_Click"  />
```

Comment: Didn't work until slightly changed to:  OnClientClick="validateLoginForm()"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Java script function with this

```
function validateLoginForm() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtTitle.ClientID%>").value == "") {

            alert("Please Enter Title");
            txtTitle.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
}
```

And you OnClientClick attribute with this

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return validateLoginForm();"
```